# Adjust element the same height as container panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, height

I have a container panel which has the possibility to expand. Inside the container panel I have an element which I want to adjust it the same height when expanded and when not expanded. How can I do it?

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  width: 895px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
  top: 60px;
}

.imageAdj {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div className="secrets-config">
  <div>
    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
    <Image className="imageAdj ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the HTML or a code snippet? it's hard to solve your CSS problem without context.

Comment: @Max see code above.

Comment: @Max my title is wrong. I should have written size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the use of `className` is only valid in JavaScript files.
Same goes for `Image`.

what you did was mostly correct only because you used `padding-bottom: 8rem;` it will never fill the whole space under your `.element`.

if you want your child element (`.element`) to be able to use `height: 100%;` you need to specify `height` in your parent element (`.container`)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 895px;
  height: auto;
  //padding-bottom: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

.element {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="link/to/file.png">
    <p>context text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```